# How can I replace a tkinter label with a new one?

Tags: python, tkinter, replace, label

I'm trying to write a fairly simple program that converts a number into binary using a tkinter GUI. The problem I'm running into is that when I enter a large number (1000 for example) and then input a smaller number (like 2) and hit submit, the new output just shows up in the middle of the old one. With the examples I used it looks something like "1000 i 2 in binary is 10 01000"

How can I remove the old label entirely right before showing the new one?

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def compute_binary():
    user_num = binary_entry.get()
    user_num = int(user_num)
    binary_equivalent = ("{:b}".format(user_num))
    binary_output = StringVar()
    binary_output.set(str(user_num) + " in binary is " + binary_equivalent)
    binary_label = Label(win, textvariable = binary_output)
    binary_label.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

win.title("Number to Binary Converter")

win.geometry("450x75")

input_request = Label(win, text = "Input a number to\nconvert to binary:")
input_request.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

binary_entry = Entry(win)
binary_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

entry_confirm = Button(win, text = "Submit", command = compute_binary)
entry_confirm.grid(row=0, column = 2)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is because you are layering labels on top of each other. Instead write your label in the global namespace and simply update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recreate new label for the result in each conversion and the new label is overlay on top of the previous label.

You need to create the result label once and update it in each conversion:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def compute_binary():
    user_num = binary_entry.get()
    user_num = int(user_num)
    binary_equivalent = ("{:b}".format(user_num))
    binary_output.set("{} in binary is {}".format(user_num, binary_equivalent))

win.title("Number to Binary Converter")

win.geometry("450x75")

input_request = Label(win, text="Input a number to\nconvert to binary:")
input_request.grid(row=0, column=0)

binary_entry = Entry(win)
binary_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

entry_confirm = Button(win, text="Submit", command=compute_binary)
entry_confirm.grid(row=0, column=2)

binary_output = StringVar()
binary_label = Label(win, textvariable=binary_output)
binary_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay I didn't realize the label would update when the variable updates, so I thought it had to be part of the command.
Also just curious, is there any benefit to the way you ran the "binary_output.set" using format rather than string concatenation?

Comment: Using `format()` is more clear and easy to read.  If in Python 3.6+, prefer to use f-string: `binary_output = f"{user_num} in binary is {binary_equivalent}"`.

Comment: Also you can combine the two `format()` into one: `binary_output = "{0} in binary is {0:b}".format(user_num)`.  Similar on the f-string.